# T-test vs Z-test

Tags: statistics, self-learning, hypothesis-testing

> It is known that the diameter of a particular type of automobile tyre follows a normal distribution with mean and variance being $600$ millimetres and $3$ millimetres respectively. Ten samples are collected from a large population of manufactured tyres as :
> [image]
> It is believed that the manufactured lot has a diameter different from $600$ mm. Which hypotheses test can be used here? What conclusion can be drawn on $H_0$.

Select one:

1. T-test, Failed to reject $H_0$
2. Z-test, Failed to reject $H_0$
3. Z-test, Reject $H_0$
4. F-test, Reject $H_0$

**Note**: I'm confused between T-test and Z-test. When one should go for T-tset and when for Z test. In this particular senario which one is best and why?

Answer (score 1):

You are given the true mean and variance of the tire diameter.  As such, you would use a $Z$-test because the test statistic does not need you to estimate the population variance from the sample.

The $F$-test is not appropriate because that is a test of variance, but the hypothesis concerns the *mean* of the sample.  The $T$-test can be used, in the sense that the testing procedure is statistically valid, but is not the test of first choice here, because it is not as powerful as a $Z$-test when you know the variance of the population.

Answer (score 0):

@Heropup (+1) is correct. Suppose the data were as entered into a recent release of Minitab, as follows:

```
 595.0   598.5   599.6   603.2   
 601.5   584.6   604.0   597.5   598.1
```

Then results of the appropriate one-sample z test
are as follows:

```
One-Sample Z: x 

Test of μ = 600 vs ≠ 600
The assumed standard deviation = 3


Variable  N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean       95% CI           Z      P
x         9  598.00   5.78     1.00  (596.04, 599.96)  -2.00  0.046
```

You reject this two-sided test at the 5% level.

You should find the sample mean $\bar X$ of your data and compute the $Z$ statistic by hand, for an exact answer.